# Is the GAE Search API actually restricted to 10,000 results?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search, google-search-api

I'm confused by conflicting documentation about how many results the Search API will actually return.

**Python & Java Docs: Restricted to 10,000 results**

- The Search API can index any number of documents. However, an index
  search can find no more than 10,000 matching documents.

  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/
- No matter how you configure the search options, a search() call will
  find no more than 10,000 matching documents.

  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/results

**Python & Java Docs: Only restricted if you sort**

- If you do not specify any sort options, your search results are automatically returned    sorted by descending rank. There is no limit to the number of documents that are returned in this case
- You can never sort more than 10,000 docs, the default is 1,000. If there are more matching documents than the number specified by SortOptions.limit, search only retrieves, sorts, and returns that limited number. If you are using sort options and it is important to retrieve every matching document, you should try to insure that your query will return no more documents than you can sort.

  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/options#Python_SortOptions

---

My use case is that I'm pushing up to 500,000 results (small record sizes) to [Crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) in the browser. Crossfilter manages all my filtering and sorting, so I don't need to sort inside the Search API. I'll be streaming those results out to the browser using [Oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/), so I should still have a fixed memory footprint, despite the large resultset.

Can I actually return any number of results as long as I don't specify a sort? If so, does that apply to Go in addition to Python and Java?

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but what would you do with more than 10,000 search results?

Comment: Good question, I just edited the question to add specifics about my use case.

Comment: I am afraid that retrieving 500,000 results will take forever and cost a fortune if you plan to do it for every user request.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin we're caching things in the browser, so most API requests will only have a few hundred or thousand, unless the users has cleared their data and needs to start from scratch.

Comment: I wish there was an answer from Google on this. The documentation is not as clear as it should be on this issue. As of this writing the bug database does not appear to have an open issue on this.